# User Profile Avatars

Tags: wp-admin

I'm using this plugin

http://wordpress.org/plugins/user-photo/

How can I get the Profile Photo that I upload through this plugin to show in the All Users list beside the Users Name and in the admin bar? I see the below codein admin-bar.php but so confused

```
/**
 * Add the "My Account" item.
 *
 * @since 3.3.0
 */
function wp_admin_bar_my_account_item( $wp_admin_bar ) {
$user_id      = get_current_user_id();
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
$profile_url  = get_edit_profile_url( $user_id );

if ( ! $user_id )
    return;

$user_info  = get_avatar( $user_id, 64 );
$user_info .= "<span class='display-name'>{$current_user->display_name}</span>";

if ( $current_user->display_name !== $current_user->user_email )
    $user_info .= "<span class='username'>&nbsp;-&nbsp;{$current_user->user_email}</span>";


$wp_admin_bar->add_menu( array(
    'id'        => 'my-account',
    'parent'    => 'top-secondary',
    'title'     => $user_info,
    'meta'      => array(
        'class'     => 'ProCorner',
        'title'     => __('My FRS ID'),
    ),
) );
```

}

Comment: Code below covers the All User List only, the admin bar is a separate issue.

Comment: @userabuser Hey, any suggestions if the custom user column called "photo" is displaying the word "array" for every profile field?

Comment: @userabuser What does the column key do? What is "user_photo" used to for?

Comment: The column key is the array key you set to specify the array item that will show itself in the users list. `$new_order[key] = value` - the value is what you physically see as the columns title. The array key is for the purpose of assigning a value (Photo) but also to order the item in the array, in this case we are inserting this item at the start of the array (left most) by searching for the `username` key and inserting out custom key before it. In the second function shown in my answer, we then use the key we specified to intercept the array pointer at this column and inject our custom data.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a custom column to the user list screen like so:

```
// Add a custom user column called Photo with a column key of user_photo 
// and re-arrange the columns array so our new column appears first.
function add_user_columns( $defaults ) {

    $new_order = array();

    foreach ( $defaults as $key => $title ) {

        if ( 'username' === $key ) {
            $new_order['user_photo'] = __( 'Photo', 'your_textdomain' );
        }

        $new_order[ $key ] = $title;

    }

    return $new_order;
}
add_filter( 'manage_users_columns', 'add_user_columns', 15 );

// Add data to our user column, specifically in your case 
// get the photo from user meta
function add_custom_user_columns( $value, $column_name, $id ) {

      if ( 'user_photo' === $column_name ) {
          // replace `$meta_key` with the relevant key that holds the photo
          return get_user_meta( $id, $meta_key, true ); 
      }

}
add_action( 'manage_users_custom_column', 'add_custom_user_columns', 15, 3 );
```

Comment: It Started a new list with photo on top and the word array in it straight down the list.